# Consulta não retorna os WHERE setados

Tags: query, informix

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta ao Banco de Dados Informix, e ela está trazendo os dados normalmente, porém está ignorando os critérios de pesquisa.

```
SELECT cnnfcapa.id_nfcapa,   
cnnfcapa.filial, cnnfitem.tpordem, 
cnnfcapa.ordemserv, cnnfcapa.dtnota,  
cnnfcapa.cgccpf, 
cnnfcapa.tppessoa, cnnfcapa.transacao, 
cttransa.mvtotransacao, 
cttransa.tipotransacao, 
cnnfcapa.id_agente, 
cnnfcapa.id_agentvext, 
cnnfitem.descritem, cnnfitem.mercadoria, 
cnnfitem.quantidade, 
cnnfitem.valoritem
FROM cnnfcapa 
INNER JOIN cnnfitem ON 
cnnfcapa.id_nfcapa = cnnfitem.id_nfcapa
INNER JOIN cttransa ON 
cnnfcapa.transacao = cttransa.transacao
WHERE dtnota BETWEEN "01/01/2015" 
AND "31/12/2015"
AND cttransa.mvtotransacao="S" 
AND cttransa.tipotransacao=10 
OR cttransa.tipotransacao=15 
OR cttransa.tipotransacao=30
OR cttransa.tipotransacao=35
```

O resultado está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os seus `OR` não estão sendo interpretados da maneira que você espera, e estão sendo aplicados em relação a todos os `AND` juntos. Faça assim:

```
WHERE dtnota BETWEEN "01/01/2015" AND "31/12/2015"
AND cttransa.mvtotransacao="S" 
AND cttransa.tipotransacao IN(10, 15, 30, 35)
```

Comment: Outra coisa: não sei detalhes do informix, mas verifique na documentação se você pode mesmo usar esse formato de data. Seria mais seguro `AAAA-MM-DD`.

Comment: É uma base da dados de terceiros. Só estou importando esses dados para a minha base MySQL. Obrigado pela dica